# Problemas na ligação a um servidor RMI

Tags: java, rmi

No servidor `RMI` tenho as seguintes configurações:

```
Registry r = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(rmiport);
r.rebind(rminame, h);
System.out.println("Servidor RMI pronto:");
```

onde, `rmiport = 7000` e `rminame=sistemas`

No cliente tenho as seguintes configurações:

```
System.out.println(rmiServerName);
 h = (ServerInterface) Naming.lookup(rmiServerName);
```

onde, `rmiServerName=rmi://194.210.172.185:7000/sistemas`

Mas ao tentar ligar obtenho a seguinte `exception`:

```
RemoteException.
```

O meu objectivo é conseguir ligar um cliente ao servidor RMI em diferentes máquinas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Servidor RMI colocar este codigo:

```
System.getProperties().put("java.security.policy", "policy.all");
System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", MEU_IP);
RMIServer rmiServer = new RMIServer();
Registry r = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(rmiport);
Naming.rebind(rminame, rmiServer);
```

No cliente RMI colocar este codigo:

```
System.getProperties().put("java.security.policy", "policy.all");
System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
h = (ServerInterface) Naming.lookup(rmiServerName);
```

Com isto o servidor já pode ser connectado a partir de outra máquina.